# Spoofing TCP/IP headers and uniqueness of the host name

Tags: ip, tcp, spoofing

I have some related questions:

1. Is it possible to spoof the source address in the TCP/IP header when using HTTPS?
2. If possible, is there any way to detect source address change? I think the checksum is not a good idea because if you can change the source address it will be the same with the checksum.
3. Is the hostname unique? For example, the IP address: 142.250.203.206 (google.com) has the hostname waw02s22-in-f14.1e100.net. Does this hostname only belong to one IP address?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to spoof the source address in the TCP/IP header when using HTTPS?

No. While it is possible to spoof the source IP address it means that the response packets gets sent to the wrong address - the spoofed ones. This makes it very hard to complete a TCP handshake (one must guess the peer initial sequence number) and practically impossible to go even further and complete a TLS handshake.

> Is the hostname unique? For example, the IP address: 142.250.203.206 (google.com) has the hostname waw02s22-in-f14.1e100.net. Does this hostname only belong to one IP address?

It is not uncommon that a hostname has multiple IP addresses. For one, it might have both IPv4 and IPv6 address but it might also have multiple IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Ok, so now I have one more question. When I type 142.250.203.206 into my browser, google.com opens. So you can identify a domain name specifically by IP address? What is the name of this operation of identifying a domain name by IP address?

Comment: It’s probably just the default website on that webserver, which is served when no host header is specified.

Comment: @Szyszka947: *"so now I have one more question"* - comments are not intended for new questions. Please ask create a new question post instead to get good answers. *"So you can identify a domain name specifically by IP address?"* - No. A domain name can have multiple IP addresses and an IP address can have multiple domain names. And this questions is actually not about information security at all, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your time and good answers.